# in a set of linear equations any way to turn an bigger then or equal to into an equal to?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm dealing with a problem where it would be very convenient if there was a way to transform an unkown matrix $A$ into a matrix $B$ such that the following holds:

If $dx$ is minimal (given constraints) and 
     $Ax \geqslant c$ 
then $Bx= c$

Anybody know if there exists any formula to determine $B$

Comment: What is $dx$ here? And if $A$ is unknown, how can we transform it?

Comment: d is a random vector A is also a random matrix, however as this is a program we are talking about just a formula or procedure to change A into B is enough.